# Analysis of a Cross-Over Design with one baseline

Tags: anova, crossover-study

My colleagues and I are designing a treatment study using a cross-over design. The subjects are going to be psychiatric inpatients and we want to see wether an exercise intervention has positive effects on cognition or not. Therefore the patients will be randomised to two different groups:
group one: exercise intervention followed by control condition
group two: control condition followed by exercise intervention

We are going to assess cognitive functions at three different time points: baseline (t1), after the completion of the exercise intervention (group one) respectively the control condition (group two, t2) and after the completion of the control condition (group one) respectively the exercise intervention (group two, t3)

Since the subjects are psychiatric inpatients who receive further treatments in addition to the intervention or control conditions, we assume that the cognitive abilities will generally improve in the course of the study. We want to find out, wether the exercise intervention leads to a stronger improvement than the control condition.

We will have various outcome variables, all of which are continuous.

We are thinking about a General Linear Model (GLM) for repeated measures with the TIME point of assessment as within-subjects factor (t1, t2, t3) and the experimental GROUP as between-subjects factor (first vs second intervention group).
But we are unsure how to account for the general improvement.
We read about the possbility to use within differences, but we are not quite sure how to do this or wether this is the right fit for our design.

We would be really happy about some advice!

Comment: What is the outcome and how is it measured?

Comment: we have various outcome variables but all are continuous

Comment: Is the outcome some sort of likert variable you are treating as continuous?  Or maybe some score on some test?  Does it have a floor or ceiling (e.g. 0-100)?  Please be more specific.

Comment: im sorry!
we have the following outcome variables:
reaction time (2-Back task)
accuracy (0-1, 2-back)
4 point likert scale for 10 items (creativity test, 0-3, maximum 30)
5 point likert scale for 18 items (Brief Symptom Inventory, 0-4, maximum 72)
5 point likert scale for 20 items ("Allgemeine Depressionsskala", 0-3, maximum 60)
Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: OK that is a lot of outcomes.  Let's focus on the primary outcome.  Which is that?  How is it measured?  Can you give me a few examples?

Comment: The primary outcome are the cognitive variables: 
n-Back-Task: During the test, a sequence of stimuli (numbers) is presented visually to the subjects. For each stimulus, a decision is made as to whether the current stimulus is the same as the one presented before two stimuli. 
Here we measure reaction time and accuracy.

Comment: creativity task: Participants are first asked to complete image fragments in an original and creative way (idea generation). This drawing is saved and finally serves as input for the next stage, the idea collaboration. In this process, participants are presented with their previously generated ideas and asked to mentally elaborate and improve the originality of them. This process is repeated for ten image fragments. Both the generated ideas and the elaborated ideas are rated on a four-point Likert scale from not original (0) to very original (3)

Comment: For the n back test, which is the measure of interest: proportion of stimuli correctly identified or average reaction time

Comment: both, the reaction time as well as the accuracy